# SQL - Get time between times

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time

I'm having a problem and don't know how can I solve it.

I have the next query and the image of the result.

```
SELECT  SCH.DAY AS 'Day', 
        convert(char(5), SCH.START_TIME, 108) AS 'Start Time', 
        convert(char(5), SCH.END_TIME, 108) AS 'End time', 
        R.ROOM_NAME AS 'Classroom',

FROM SECTIONSCHEDULE SCH
INNER JOIN ROOM R ON SCH.ROOM_ID = R.ROOM_ID
WHERE R.ROOM_NAME = 'AU 401' AND SCH.DAY = 'MONDAY'
```

What I do there is that I get the Day, Start Time, End time and the classroom where the class is going to be. I have two tables, on the ROOM table I only have the Room_ID and the name of the room, while on the other table "SectionSchedule" I have the day in which that classroom is going to be occupied, the time when the class begins (SCH.Start_Time) and the time when the class is going to finish (SCH.END_TIME). Start_Time and End_Time are of the type "DateTime"..So, on the next image I'm going to show you the time when the room "AU 401" is going to be occupied.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3KG.png]

But now this is the part where I'm stuck. I have to get the exact time when the classroom is not going to be occupied, so as you saw on the previous image that classroom is going to be occupied from 14:05 PM to 17:05 PM and 20:47 PM to 22:47 PM. The classes at the school begin at 07:00 AM, so I have to show something like:

07:00 AM to 14:05 PM

17:05 PM to 20:47 PM

22:47 PM to 24:00 PM

But I don't know how to get that, I was using DateDifference where I get the difference between End_Time and Start_Time, but I'm only getting "3 hours" and "2 hours". So I'm not sure how to get what I want.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Look up islands and gaps. This is a pretty common thing to have to do.

Comment: Ok, going to check that up.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
WITH cteNotEmpty
AS
(
    SELECT
        SCH.DAY AS 'Day', 
        convert(char(5), SCH.START_TIME, 108) AS 'StartTime', 
        convert(char(5), SCH.END_TIME, 108) AS 'EndTime', 
        R.ROOM_NAME AS 'Classroom',
    FROM
        SECTIONSCHEDULE SCH
        JOIN ROOM R ON SCH.ROOM_ID = R.ROOM_ID
    WHERE R.ROOM_NAME = 'AU 401' AND SCH.DAY = 'MONDAY'
)

SELECT
    Q.[Day]
    , Q.Classroom
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN L <> StartTime THEN L
            WHEN L IS NULL AND StartTime <> '07:00:00' THEN '07:00:00'
            ELSE NULL
        END EmptyStartTime
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN L <> StartTime THEN StartTime
            WHEN L IS NULL AND StartTime <> '07:00:00' THEN StartTime
            ELSE NULL
        END EmptyEndTime
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Day]
            , StartTime
            , Classroom
            , LAG(EndTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [Day], Classroom ORDER BY EndTime) L
        FROM cteNotEmpty
    ) Q
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN L <> StartTime THEN L
        WHEN L IS NULL AND StartTime <> '07:00:00' THEN '07:00:00'
        ELSE NULL
    END IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT
    Q.[Day]
    , Q.Classroom
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN L <> EndTime THEN EndTime
            WHEN L IS NULL AND EndTime <> '23:59:59' THEN EndTime
            ELSE NULL
        END EmptyStartTime
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN L <> EndTime THEN L
            WHEN L IS NULL AND EndTime <> '23:59:59' THEN '23:59:59'
            ELSE NULL
        END EmptyEndTime
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [Day]
            , EndTime
            , Classroom
            , LEAD(StartTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [Day], Classroom ORDER BY StartTime) L
        FROM cteNotEmpty
    ) Q
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN L <> EndTime THEN EndTime
        WHEN L IS NULL AND EndTime <> '23:59:59' THEN EndTime
        ELSE NULL
    END IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY
    [Day]
    , Classroom
    , EmptyStartTime
```